# Set ng-model value on <tabset> <tab> when active

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Is it possible to set a $scope value on a tab when its active?

Example: 3 tabs with ng-model="tabID" on each. Then {{tabID}} would be either 1,2,3,4 depending on what tab is active.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put ng-click inside tab:

```
<tabset>
   <tab ng-model="tabID" ng-click="activate(1)">
      <tab-heading><i class="fa fa-bell"></i> First tab</tab-heading>
      <tab-content> 
         fixed tab content 
      </tab-content>
   </tab>
   <tab ng-model="tabID" ng-click="activate(2)">
      <tab-heading><i class="fa fa-bell"></i> Second tab</tab-heading>
      <tab-content> 
         Content 
      </tab-content>
   </tab>
   <tab ng-model="tabID" ng-click="activate(3)">
      <tab-heading><i class="fa fa-bell"></i> Third Tab</tab-heading>
      <tab-content> 
         content 
      </tab-content>
   </tab>
</tabset>
```

In your javascript (controller):

```
$scope.activate=function(i)
    {
        $scope.tabID=i;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! If my tabs where created from af array of say; data=[{id:"foo",title:"bar"},{id:"foo1",title:"bar1"},{id:"foo2",title:"bar2"},{id:"foo3",title:"bar3"}] using ng-repeat and the text on the tab would be "title" value? Could i then pass in the {{data.title}} inside ng-click"activate({{data.title}})?

Comment: Of course but do not use curly brackets in ng-click. Do it like this:  <tab ng-model="tabID" ng-repeat = "d in data" ng-click="activate(d.id)">

Comment: I am glad to help. Please mark my answer as correct one

Answer (score 0):

You can have one variable which stores which tab is selected and onclick change the tab value

```
$scope.changeTab=function(index)
    {
        $scope.selectedtabID=index;

    }
```